# Unable to build Gradle project in IntelliJ 11.0.2 + Windows 7

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have been successfully using a gradle project on Ubantu and wanted to set up same in Windows 7. I tried with Grade Milestone 3 and 7 but have always encountered error - "can not resolve target gradle project". Has any one else also come across it?

[image: Gradle project failure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to configure the same Gradle home in `Settings` | `Gradle` | `Gradle home` before creating the new project, [there is a known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-78546) with the New Project Gradle home setting being ignored.

[Another possible case of the problem](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-80374).

If it still doesn't work, [please file a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) with [idea.log](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) attached.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem; it can be resolved by using the following versions of both tools

- IntelliJ Utimate Version - **11.1.1**
- Gradle - Milsetone **1.0-milestone-9**